# List Loopback model properties

Tags: model, loopbackjs

Is there any way to list all the properties on a model in Loopback? I'd like to be able to get more than just the name when I call loopback.models() to get the model list. I'd like to build a generic dashboard that will automatically generate forms to edit my models, but to do so I need to be able to enumerate model properties.

Comment: FWIW, if you are looking for a generic dashboard that will automatically generate forms to edit your models, then you should check out https://github.com/beeman/loopback-angular-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's javascript, so in a boot script like `./server/boot/printall.js` you can explore all props of all models

```
module.exports = function(app) {
   for(var i = 0 ; i < app.models.length ; i++) {
      for(prop in app.models[i]) {
         console.log(prop)
      }
   }
}
```

To build the dashbord client-side, I would recommend to use the swagger.json file that contains all of these information and is accessible client-side at `http://localhost:3000/explorer/resources` (loopback 1.2) or `http://localhost:3000/explorer/swagger.json` (loopback 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

We can use code as following:

```
module.exports = function(MyModel) {
    MyModel.getProperties = () => {
        return MyModel.definition.properties;
    }
}
```

This code works in loopback 3. I'm not sure that it works well in loopback 4.